# Trying to build triangle of symbols in Python

Tags: python

So my professor is trying to get us to write a function within a function that prints a triangle of different symbols, like this:

&

&

&&

%

%%

%%%

@

@@

@@@

@@@@

I can write the triangle function and have it print in that format, but I'm having a difficult time making the mental leap to attach a variable symbol element. In short, I can print the proper shape, but not with different symbols. Here's what I have so far:

```
s = "&"
def stars(i):
    '''Prints n number of stars'''
    print(i*s)

def triangle_of_symbols(s, n):
    '''Creates symbol triangle function with variable n.'''
    for i in range (n):
        stars(i+1)

triangle_of_symbols(s, 1)

triangle_of_symbols(s, 2)

triangle_of_symbols(s, 3)

triangle_of_symbols(s, 4)
```

How would I accomplish this? Even being pointed in the right direction would be enormously helpful right now.

Comment: This is, by the way, a rare example of a trivial question that's well-asked and imminently answerable.

Answer (score 4):

Your `stars` function currently takes `i`, which is how many stars to print, and then pulls from the global variable `s` for what symbol to print.

Instead, parameterize `s` in `stars` so you can tell the function which symbol to print on each call.

```
def starts(i, s):
    print(s * i)  # I think that order scans better -- "s, i times". YMMV
```

Then in `triangle_of_symbols` pass `s` along with `i+1`.

```
...
for i in range(n):
    stars(i+1, s)
```

though really there's little reason to separate the two functions.

```
def triangle_of_stars(s, n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(s * i+1)
```

Comment: just wanted to post that ;), +1

Comment: I think he's trying to get us comfortable with using helper functions. I'm very new to all of this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CodeBlue04 would make sense. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

You can also put your symbols in a dictionary.

```
shapes = {"stars": "*", "at": "@"}


def generate_triangle(shape_key, lines):
    for i in range(lines):
        print (shapes[shape_key] * (i+1))


generate_triangle('at', 4)
generate_triangle('stars', 4)
```

Comment: You could consider using an `Enum` for this, too! [see this snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1660107)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for sharing.